# Xcode - Imposible generate for iOS App Store Deployment

Tags: ios, xcode

As title is pointing, I'm able to generate and IPA for `ad hoc` deployment but when I try to do the same for App store the error "You already have an iOS Distribution Valid certificate"

I'm using the same provisioning profile and I have already check if provisioning profile is using the valid certificate and it does.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using a different mac for deploying?

Comment: I'm using the same macbook pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a provisioning profile to adhoc, but what I need was generate another provisioning profile for distribution.

So I have finally 3 provisioning profile:

1. Development Provisioning profile
2. Adhoc Provisioning profile
3. Distribution Provisioning profile